SQL - Czech character encoding from UTF-8 HEX
Does anyone know if there is a function that converts URF-8 HEX characters included in search queries back to the original encoding, for example:
https://www.bambule.cz/vyhledavani/?search=hasi%C4%8Di+lego
%C4%D8 means letter č in my language. So the result should be a world hasiči. If there is any special character I need to convert.
Thanks a lot for your help.
I use Big query database system.

Use below approach
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION decode_url(encoded STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return decodeURIComponent(encoded);
""";
SELECT
  url,
  decode_url(REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'search=([^&]*)')) AS decoded_search
FROM your_data;

If to apply to your sample data
WITH your_data AS (
  SELECT 'https://www.bambule.cz/vyhledavani/?search=hasi%C4%8Di+lego' AS url
)

the output is


Hello, thank you for your answer, your function works in case this particular example well, but if I apply to whole dataset (contains about 500K URLS) getting this error   -   URIError: URI malformed at decode_url(STRING) line 2, columns 9-10. Any ideas what is error means? Thanks

just found what is causing this issue - https://www.bambule.cz/vyhledavani/?search=lego+sleva+30%, - % at the end of the string, probably need to replace before
